# Automatic Event Scheduling

Tags: php, sql, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a project that has daily events. I would like to make it so that the events get deleted at a certain time and then add a new event for the next day. All of the events start and end at the same time every day.

I do not have access to the event scheduler in MySQL and my host will not turn it on.

Is there a way to do this so I don't have to schedule the events (19 of them) every day?

Comment: I'd take a look at **Cron Jobs**.

Comment: Neither PHP nor SQL are the right tools for this task. You should schedule a cron job using the servers operating system.

Comment: I can not use Cron Jobs as the base OS is Windows.

Comment: @Matt No, but you can write a Windows script and execute it using the Task Scheduler.

Comment: This may be too simplistic a view of things, but if it's the same 19 events every day, all you would need to do is change the underlying date information?

Comment: BobDuell: I don't have access to the host computer. RayPaseur: The thing is that people 'register' for the events. I would somehow need to delete all of the registered users from the event before changing the date. If that makes sense...